# Passing String through Socket duplicates value

Tags: java, sockets, printwriter

I am creating a simple Client-Server application and facing some weird behaviour when passing messages through a Socket: When the Client writes to the server, the message is passed correctly, however when the server sends a response, whichever value is sent through the socket seems to get duplicated...

Here is a sample code of what the server does:

```
.
.
.
public void respond(Socket socket)
{
    try
    {
        InputStreamReader inStream = new InputStreamReader( socket.getInputStream() );
        PrintWriter outStream = new PrintWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter( socket.getOutputStream(), "UTF-16" ) );

        outStream.write("Message received\n");
        outStream.flush();

        .
        .
        .
    }
    catch (Exception e) { /* Do something */ }
}
.
.
.
```

Server and Client are currently running on the same machine.

Furthermore, encoding seems to be no issue when writing from client to server, but it is when writing from server to client: If I specify any other (or no) encoding than UTF-16 for the OutputStreamWriter, the Client won't be able to parse the message correctly.

Does any of you guys have an idea why that might be?

Comment: I think you made a mistake pasting your code, taht does not compile (duplicate variables).

Comment: It's possible that your code isn't actually being compiled, and is instead running on an existing compilation, because you have the same code block in there twice, resulting in a duplicate variable error.

Comment: Sry, that happened when pasting, I edited it, still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

The character encoding on each end of the conversation needs to be the same: the `Charset` used for encoding by `InputStreamReader` at the client must match that used by the `OutputStreamWriter` at the server (and vice-versa).

If you don't specify one, it is going to use the JVM's default.

When you didn't provided your client's code, the fact that the server is using the default `Charset` to read and `UTF-16` to write makes me think there is a potential mismatch.

Comment: I ran the code for client and server on the same machine, so default encoding should be the same I guess?

Comment: I think you misunderstand me (but will clarify my answer).  Your server's `InputStreamReader` (above) does not specify a `Charset`, so it is using the default one.  If the `OutputStreamReader` on the client side is setting it to `UTF-16`, then there will be a mismatch unless `UTF-16` is the default for your platform.